# I made a simple website using html,css and php. Website works fine when opened directly in browser but fails to load on local server

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have created a simple website using HTML, CSS, and PHP. When I open the .html file directly in my browser, everything works perfectly. However, when I try to load the same website on my local server (i.e. XAMPP), it fails to load properly.

I am attaching the images below of how it should look and how it is looking on the local server.
[This is how the site should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VGrX.png)
[This is how it is behaving on the local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oso53.png)

Here's what I've tried so far:

- **Checked the file paths**: I've made sure that all file paths in my HTML and PHP files are correct and relative to the root directory of my project.
- **Checked server configurations**: I've checked the server configurations in my local server software to ensure that PHP is enabled and that the server is properly configured to serve PHP files.
- **Checked error logs**: I've looked at the error logs of my local server to see if there are any errors or warnings related to my website's files.
- **Checked permissions**: I've made sure that the permissions on my files and directories are set correctly so that the server can read and execute them.

Despite trying these troubleshooting steps, I'm still unable to get my website to load properly on my local server.

Comment: Check the browser developer tools, network tab, there's some different or missing CSS that is changing the way the HTML renders.

Comment: I suggest you use the browser developer tools, the console can tell you what kind of issues are you having and why your styles won't load properly.
Also, I can see that in the second image you're serving your application on the localhost, so you need to adjust the links and paths of your assets to point there instead of the path to your `D:` disk.

Comment: @Eyad I did adjust the links and the paths, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Anarchy: In your browser's development tools, are there any errors on the console?  On the Network tab, when doing a full reload of the page (generally Ctrl-F5), do any resources fail to load?  For any given element on the page which doesn't have the styling you expect, when you examine that element in the DOM explorer, what styles are applied to it and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: I figured out that chrome is causing this problem, I tried running the same on Firefox, its working well over there, any reason why this is happening?

Comment: @Anarchy my guess is that some extension may be causing this issue. Try opening your website on an incognito instance of Google Chrome and see if the problem persists or not, if all works well then we're talking about an extension that may be blocking some resources from loading correctly.
You can try disabling the extensions one by one until you find the offending extension.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @eyah bereh's suggestion, I was able to identify the culprit as a Chrome extension.

Running the application in incognito mode, which disables extensions by default, resolved the problem. This suggests that one of my extensions was interfering with the normal functionality.

I'm still investigating further to pinpoint the exact extension, but for now, using incognito mode or temporarily disabling extensions allows me to work around the issue.